# Enable button only if both textview are non-empty in Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm doing a sign in page with two TextView and one Button. By default, the sign in button(btnSignin) is disabled. The button should be enabled only if both TextViews are non-empty.
I tried this code, and it is working partially. But the Button react only to first textView(txtId). If the second textView is changed after the first, nothing happening.

Here I just erased two @override function for convenience.

```
    usernameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtId);
    passwordTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    final Button signinBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignin);

    usernameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            signinBtn.setEnabled( (!usernameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) & (!passwordTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) );
        }
    });
```

Comment: the code is working on a single textView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
usernameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtId);
passwordTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
final Button signinBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignin);

usernameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        signinBtn.setEnabled( (!usernameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) && (!passwordTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) );
    }
});
```

And Also for

```
passwordTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        signinBtn.setEnabled( (!usernameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) && (!passwordTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) );
    }
});
```

Comment: i think a single '&' is enough.. just forget to add textChange listener to passwordTxt

Comment: `&` evaluates both sides of the operation. Which means even if Left side of operation false , it continues to evaluate Right side as well.
`&&` evaluates the left side of the operation, if it's true, then it continues and evaluates the right side.

Answer (score 1):

This following piece of code is registering just userName text field ,You need to add something like this for the **passwordTxt**

```
usernameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            signinBtn.setEnabled( (!usernameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) & (!passwordTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) );
        }
    });
```

That is you are specifying listeners for **usernameTxt**,but not for **passwordTxt**.Supply one to it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a listener for the second `textview`. Add a listener for `passwordTxt`

```
passwordTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            signinBtn.setEnabled( (!usernameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) & (!passwordTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) );
        }
    });
```